# The onItemChangeListener crashes

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

So I am currently working on a spinner that changes entries in a list. When loading into the Fragment and loading the List into the spinner adapter and setting up the onItemChangedListener everything works fine. But when the App goes to another Fragment and then goes back the app crashes with the following exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de.heffnersoftware.hsproduction, PID: 13111
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter view
    at de.heffnersoftware.hsproduction.ui.storeManagement.ListFiveFragment$onCreateView$3.onItemSelected(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:957)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:946)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.selectionChanged(AdapterView.java:935)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.checkSelectionChanged(AdapterView.java:1118)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.handleDataChanged(AdapterView.java:1094)
    at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:193)
    at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:614)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure(AppCompatSpinner.java:438)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24721)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24721)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:811)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:466)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:134)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:278)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:120)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1594)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1708)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24721)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6903)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24721)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:811)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:466)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:134)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:278)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:120)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1594)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1708)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24721)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6903)
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:99)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:2227)
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:831)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24721)
    at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1156)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24721)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6903)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24721)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6903)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24721)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6903)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24721)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6903)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24721)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6903)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:743)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24721)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3135)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1900)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2200)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1788)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7867)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:967)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:791)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:726)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:952)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7399)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:502)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
```

Bellow is the Listener and code surrounding it:

```
    val spinner: Spinner = root.findViewById(R.id.store_select_spinner)
        val spinnerAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(
            requireContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, llNames
        )
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item)
        spinner.adapter = spinnerAdapter

        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View,
                position: Int,
                id: Long
            ) {

            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems like you only need to change `View` to `View?` in the `onItemSelected` parameters.

Comment: Where is `spinner` being declared? Is this done in `onViewCreated`? Showing more of the code where `spinner` is declared may be useful as it could be an issue of referencing a view that no longer exists.

Comment: @undermark5 the spinner is being declared in the OnCreateView Function, but so is the Listener.

Comment: @Demigod I have kept your fix but am unable to test that case because that is happening very rarely, I will confirm after some days of build release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error has been solved by the solution Demigod provided.

The code needs to be altered as the following:

```
       spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                id: Long
            ) {
               StoreListFragment.storeAdapter.changeShelve(llShelveNames[position].first)
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
            }
        }
```